# Convergence test and remainders

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty {a_n}$ be a positive convergent sequence, whose convergence was decided by:

a) [Cauchy's root test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_root_test). Then $R_n \leq {q^{n+1}\over 1-q}$.

b) [Ratio test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test). Then $R_n \leq {a_{n+1}\over 1-q}$.

Prove these two inequalities hold.

The textbook doesn't say what $R_n$ is, I guess it is $R_n = \lim_{k\to \infty} (\sum\limits_{n=1}^k {a_n}) - \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} {a_i}$.

I tried for b) (inequality following from the criterion):

$R_{n+1} = a_{n+2} + a_{n+3}... \leq qa_{n+1} + qa_{n+2} + .. = R_n q = R_{n+1}q + a_{n+1}q$, which however implies just $R_{n+1} < {a_{n+1}\over 1-q}$...

Comment: What's the question, anyway??

Comment: I am looking for a proof of the two statements.

Comment: Then write that *explicitly*, @mirgee...and what "two* statements? Common, read your question: it isn't  clear!

Comment: I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: What book is that that doesn't say what $\;R_n\;$ is? It looks like some kind of remainder...or perhaps some convergence radius...It is odd.

Comment: Yes, $R_n = \sum\limits_{k=n+1}^\infty a_k$. It's an application of the triangle inequality combined with the estimates for $a_k$ that you get from the respective test. But both estimates hold only for large enough $n$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Thanks for advice, but I'm still struggling, could you please elaborate??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root test says that if

$$c := \limsup_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{\lvert a_n\rvert} < 1,$$

then $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ is absolutely convergent. By the definition of $\limsup$, it follows that for all $q > c$ there is an $N(q)\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\sqrt[n]{\lvert a_n\rvert} \leqslant q$ for all $n > N(q)$. Of course, $\sqrt[n]{\lvert a_n\rvert} \leqslant q$ is equivalent to $\lvert a_n\rvert \leqslant q^n$. Now if we choose $q \in (c,1)$, we find

$$\lvert R_n\rvert = \left\lvert \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty a_k\right\rvert \leqslant \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \lvert a_k\rvert \leqslant \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty q^k = \frac{q^{n+1}}{1-q}$$

for all $n \geqslant N(q)$.

Similarly, the ratio test asserts that if $a_n \neq 0$ for all $n$ and

$$d := \limsup_{n\to\infty} \left\lvert \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right\rvert < 1,$$

then $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ is absolutely convergent. Like for the root test, for every $q \in (d,1)$ we find an $N(q)\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for $n > N(q)$ we have $\left\lvert \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right\rvert \leqslant q$, and then it follows that

$$\lvert a_{n+k}\rvert = \lvert a_n\rvert \cdot \prod_{m=1}^k \left\lvert \frac{a_{n+m}}{a_{n+m-1}}\right\rvert \leqslant \lvert a_n\rvert\cdot q^k.$$

Therefore, for $n \geqslant N(q)$ we have

$$\lvert R_n\rvert = \left\lvert \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_{n+1+k}\right\rvert \leqslant \sum_{k=0}^\infty \lvert a_{n+1+k}\rvert \leqslant \sum_{k=0}^\infty \lvert a_{n+1}\rvert\cdot q^k = \lvert a_{n+1}\rvert \sum_{k00}^\infty q^k = \frac{\lvert a_{n+1}\rvert}{1-q}.$$

Here, all $a_n$ are assumed positive, hence the absolute value can be ignored/omitted wherever it occurs.